# IE url limitation, How to overcome when creating files to download?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, csv, uri, href

As IE url limit is 2083 characters ([see here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)). I have problems creating a csv file to download:

My script fails in this line: `link.href = uri;`

where `var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);`

and `CSV` is actually a string with the content of the file.

So, how could I resolve this issue without limiting the file content to 2083 characters?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't really a way without creating the file on a server and sending it. If you need to stay client-side, putting the csv data in a textbox is your best hope.

**UPDATE**: Just had a quick think about this, you might have better luck if you put your data-uri as the href of an `a` element, aka

```
var ae = document.createElement 'a';
ae.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

document.appendChild(ae);
```

Comment: That's how is it now and unfortunately is not resolving the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
    var downloadCSV = document.createElement('a');
downloadCSV.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(finalOutput));
downloadCSV.setAttribute('download', 'Report.csv');
downloadCSV.click();
```

Try this, I've had some success with it in chrome, I think you can pass up to 2mb with it.
I've also encountered a lot of problems in creating a CSV on the client side...